# Is it possible to train a tensorflow production model?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, neural-network, training-data

If I build a model and train it, then deploy it. Can I set it up to train on data at runtime? E.g. if I wanted a net that could just train on constant input until I stopped it and tested it. Would I have to Implement that by talking to the protobuffer in C++?

Answer (score 0):

The practical problem with neural networks in production is that you train on known output, but apply them in production in order to create output. That usually precludes in-production updates.

Yet, there's no magic involved. If in production you can still get the desired output (even in hindsight) for a given input, then you can backpropagate the resulting error term and adjust the network weights.

There's an additional challenge here: if you train the network in production, what data are you intending to train with? Initially you can't train on just the first few samples from the field, as you'd greatly overtrain on those. So you'll need to include the initial training set in the deployed solution, and expand on that.